# If $T=I-B$ then $\lambda_i(T)=1-\lambda_i(B)$ where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$ eigenvalue of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Jacobi methods of my book, I came across with the following statement:

> If $T=I-B$ then:
> $$
> \lambda_i(T)=1-\lambda_i(B)
> $$

where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$ eigenvalue of $B$. I guess it is more general than "Jacobi methods". I'm trying to figure out why it's true and I can't seem to figure how to prove it. Is it possible to show how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean that $\lambda_i(B)$ is the ith eigenvalue of B and that $\lambda_i(T)$ is the ith eigenvalue of T.  Saying that $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of B means that there is some vector, v, such that $B(v)= \lambda_i v$.   Then $D(v)= (I- B)v= Iv- Bv= v- \lambda_i v= (1- \lambda_i)v$.